# Proof about equality of sets (increasing sets)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $B$ be some subset of the metric space $(X,d)$.

Suppose there exists closed subsets $\{ B_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset X$, such that $B = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}$.

Now let's say I define for every $k \geq 1$, the sets $F_{k} := \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{k}B_{n}$.

How do I formally prove that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n} = B$?

MY ATTEMPT:

Suppose $x \in B = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}$. Then there exists an $k\geq 1$ such that $x \in B_{k}$. Then $x \in \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{k}B_{j}=F_{k}$. Since there exists a $k$ for which $x \in F_{k}$, we get that $x \in \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{k}$. Then $B \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{k}$.

Suppose $x \in \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{k}$. Then there exists a $k \geq 1$ such that $x \in F_{k} = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{k}B_{n}$. Then there exists an $n$, where $1 \leq n \leq k$ such that $x \in B_{n}$. Then there exists some $n \geq 1$ for which $x \in B_{n}$. Then $x \in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n} = B$. Then $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{k} \subseteq B$.

Then $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{k} = B$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Notice that it doesn't matter what the sets $B_n$ are. They can be any sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is quite correct. Another way, essentially the same:

For all $i$, $B_i \subseteq F_i$, so $\cup_j B_j \subseteq \cup_j F_j$.

Also for all $k$, $F_k = \cup_{i = 0}^k B_i \subseteq \cup_j B_j$, so also $\cup_j F_j \subseteq \cup_j B_j$.

Comment: This is much easier than what I have put. Thank you!

Comment: @Greg.Paul Really, it's essentially the same argument. Yours is just more explicit. But glad to help!